# How can I pass two lamdas in this situation to define my function in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose

My question is simple and not as complicated as it might look like, so I have the function CoinListItem that has the following parameters, the first two parameters are two different Json domains that I need to use to display some items from them into the UI using Jetpack compose.

```
@Composable
fun CoinListItem (
coin: Coin,
coinDetail: CoinDetail, //
onItemClick: (Coin) -> Unit
) {
Row(
    modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable { onItemClick(coin) }
        .padding(20.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
 ) {
    Text(
        text = "${coin.rank}. ${coin.name} (${coin.symbol})",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
    Text(
        text = if(coin.isActive) "active" else "inactive",
        color = if(coin.isActive) Color.Green else Color.Red,
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
        modifier = Modifier.align(CenterVertically)
    )
   
    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter("${coinDetail.logo}"),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp)

    ) 
   }

}
```

now in my CoinListScreen function below, and generally,
specifically at  items(state.coins) { coin -> ,
I want to do something like,  items(state.coins) { coin -> , coinDetail ->

but I'm not sure if it's even possible, or how is it possible if so. Otherwise, I get an error that It cannot resolve the reference coinDetail

```
@Composable
fun CoinListScreen(
navController: NavController,
viewModel: CoinListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
val state = viewModel.state.value
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
 items(state.coins) { coin -> **// I want to define coinDetail here as well**                 
            CoinListItem(
                coin = coin,
               // coinDetail = coinDetail**,//this doesn't work ofcourse   if coinDetail -> is not initialized**
                onItemClick = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.CoinDetailScreen.route +     "/${coin.id}")
                }
            )
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: where that CoinDetail came from ? do you have list containing CoinDetail in your viewModel ? and what is the relation between Coin and CoinDetail why you didn't just put everything in Coin

Comment: @MoCoding Coin and Coin detail are two different Json's that I've parsed so they both have their separate domain, I need an entry from coin detail to be used in the coin screen.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the relation between `Coin` and `CoinDetail` it will be difficult to provide an exact answer, but here is something that will hopefully at least provide a nudge.

We need to associated each coin with the corresponding detail because `Coin` doesn't contain `CoinDetail` (it really probably should, but if it can't for some reason we will ignore this). One way to accomplish that could be something like this

```kotlin
state.coins.zipWith(state.coinDetails)
```

Downside, is this assumes that the two are both in lists of the same size and the order of the two matches (that is, that the details for `coins[i]` is `coinDetails[i]`). If that is not the case, then in order to make the relation, either the `Coin` or `CoinDetail` has an ID for the relating data (at least one needs it, both could have it).

If we have this ID we can do something like this

```kotlin
val coinDetailsMap Map<Coin, CoinDetails?> = coins.associateWith { coin ->
    details.firstOrNull { detail ->
        detail.id == coin.id
    }
}
```

The above way will search through the entire list of details every time, if you want a slightly more performant approach this will only go through the details one time

```kotlin
val detailsMap: Map<String, CoinDetails> = details.associateBy(CoinDetails::id)
val coinDetailsMap Map<Coin, CoinDetails?> = coins.associateWith { coin ->
    detailsMap[coin.detailsId]
}
```

Once you have some form of pairing between a `Coin` and a `CoinDetails` object you can pass `Pair<Coin,CoinDetail>` to the `items` function and get them via destructuring `items(pairs) { (coin, details) -> /* ... */ }`